# Building SQL query to join three tables to get messaging info

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables for a messaging system:

```
`messaging_messagethread`
- id
- subject
- initiator_id # who creates the thread
- recipient_id

`messaging_message`
- id
- thread_id
- content
- timestamp
- sender_id

`messaging_messagestatus` # a status will be created for each recipient of a message
- id
- message_id
- recipient_id
- status
```

Given a user, I need to build a query to get the following:

- Show Thread ID (distinct),
- `content` and `timestamp` of the most recent message in that thread
- Remove any threads with the most recent message `status='deleted'`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT thread.id as thread_id, timestamp.timestamp 
    FROM messaging_messagethread thread 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT thread_id, MAX(timestamp) as timestamp
      FROM messaging_message GROUP BY thread_id) timestamp
      ON thread.id = timestamp.thread_id
WHERE initiator_id = 4 OR thread.recipient_id = 4 ORDER BY timestamp.timestamp DESC
```

This gives me distinct thread id's ordered by most recent timestamp. (My first of three points). How would I build the entire query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subqueries to get the most recent message of a particular thread. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    b.content, 
    b.timestamp
FROM
    messaging_messagethread a
INNER JOIN
    messaging_message b ON a.id = b.thread_id 
WHERE 
    b.timestamp = 
    (
        SELECT MAX(timestamp) 
        FROM messaging_message 
        WHERE thread_id = a.id
    )
    AND b.id NOT IN
    (
        SELECT message_id
        FROM messaging_messagestatus
        WHERE status = 'deleted'
    )
    AND 4 IN (a.initiator_id, a.recipient_id)
ORDER BY
    b.timestamp DESC
```

If I understand you correctly, I believe this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you want the latest message from each thread,
unfortunately there's no way to retrieve the top member withing a group AFAIK
So what Im doing is basically getting all the messages from each thread_id 
that the user is related to then simply returning the top id ... oh and checking
that message hasn't being deleted.
IM NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT.

But please reconsider a different approach maybe using a programming language,
or multiple queries.
CAUSE THIS IS GOING TO BE SLOW...

```
SELECT thread_id, content, timestamp
FROM messaging_message
WHERE messaging_message.id IN
(
    SELECT messaging_message.id
    FROM messaging_message
        INNER JOIN messaging_messagestatus ON
            (messaging_messagestatus.message_id = messaging_message.id)
    WHERE messaging_message.thread_id IN
            (SELECT DISTINCT id 
             FROM messaging_messagethread
             WHERE initiator_id = 4 OR recipient_id = 4) AND
         messaging_messagestatus.status != 'deleted'
     ORDER BY timestamp DESC
     LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

good luck.