# Improve subselect query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do the following query without a subselect?

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM messaging_message WHERE recipient_id=4 ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) combined
GROUP BY thread_id HAVING status='unread'
```

Table:

```
`messaging_message`
 - id
 - thread_id
 - content
 - sender_id
 - recipient_id
 - timestamp
 - status
```

Thread ID is the parent thread for the messages.

**Update**: In testing the two answers so far, neither query is generating the results that I need.

The query should return ONLY those results where the most recent message in the message thread = 'unread'. Both of the below queries are returning the top-most result of ANY thread that has a message with status = 'unread'.

What I am trying to do is something like any email inbox, for example Gmail. Let's say the inbox shows 25 threads on the first page. I want to highlight ONLY those threads that have the most recent message with status = 'unread' (ignoring the status of any message older than the most recent one).

This is also why I'm using the `GROUP BY` on the ordered results, so that I ONLY get the most recent result, and out of those results, see which one has status='unread'

(Note that I also changed the status in the above query from 'deleted' to 'unread' so I could make the explanation more clear.)

Comment: What is `thread_id`? Can you describe the table. Please.

Comment: Something doesn't look right.  Don't you have to aggregate all the other columns not in the `group by`?

Comment: The `GROUP BY` in the parent query will be unaffected by the `ORDER BY` in the subquery: as [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) states, "*The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.*".

Comment: @eggyal thanks for pointing that out and including the manual link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to be clear, you're trying to retrieve the details of the most recent deleted message in each thread where the recipient of that message is user_id 4... correct? If so, this question is similar to the one you posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958245/building-sql-query-to-join-three-tables-to-get-messaging-info) and seems like you've merged your messagestatus table into your messages table (good!). So here is my adjusted answer:

```
SELECT 
    b.*
FROM 
    messaging_messagethread a
INNER JOIN 
    messaging_message b ON a.id = b.thread_id
WHERE 
    b.timestamp =
    (
        SELECT MAX(timestamp)
        FROM messaging_message
        WHERE thread_id = a.id
    )
    AND b.status = 'unread'
    AND b.recipient_id = 4
```

Here, we're using a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to extract the timestamp of the most recent message for each thread.

Then we check if that message has a status of 'unread'.

Finally in the third condition in the WHERE clause, we only select the threads where the recipient of the last deleted message is user_id 4.

Comment: Please see the update in the question, in which I explain the query I am looking to get.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying further, I understand your problem now. See my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is something of a MySQL hack.  The SQL standard does not allow an `order by` in that position.  I'm not even sure that it will work consistently in MySQL.  Having said that, your version  is fairly clear and probably outperforms a more strict version.

For example, a more official way of writing your query would be:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  distinct thread_id
        from    messaging_message
        where   recipient_id = 4
        ) thread
join    messaging_message mm
on      mm.id =
        (
        select  mm2.id
        from    messaging_message mm2
        where   thead.thread_id = mm2.thread_id
        order by
                mm2.timestamp desc
        limit   1
        )
where   mm.status = 'unread'
```

Comment: Please see the update in the question, in which I explain the query I am looking to get.